# How can I disappear the Dialog once log out has been performed?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Once I click the button log-out, it does log me out of the site, however, the dialog does not disappear not unless i'll click the screen outside of the dialog. How can I make the dialog disappear once I have clicked the log out button?

```
                   <Dialog
                        open={open}
                        onClose={handleClose}
                        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
                        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
                    >
                        <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">{"Logging Out?"}</DialogTitle>
                        <DialogContent>
                        <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
                           Thank you for visiting our site. See you again!
                        </DialogContentText>
                        </DialogContent>
                        <DialogActions>
                        <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
                            Cancel
                        </Button>
                        <Button onClick={() => signOut()} color="primary" autoFocus>
                            LogOut
                        </Button>
                        </DialogActions>
                </Dialog>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `handleClose` to your `onClick` handler

```
<Button onClick={() =>{
   signOut()
   handleClose()
}} color="primary" autoFocus>
```